# how can i include old file in dynamo db aws new index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

i have a table in dynamo with only one partition index, i created another one on another string field but it is not populated with the old data, can anyone explain me why?

I've tried several things to populate it but it always stays at 0

thanks guys

PS my dynamo is on aws

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to see the number of items in an index that you created? If you are looking at the item count in the console or by using DeacribeTable API then you wont see an up to date value as its updat once every 6 hour approx.

You can do a live item count on th console or you can use Scan with Select=COUNT parameter.

CLI Example:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name myTable \
--index-name myIndex \
--select COUNT
```